# Flex - Issues vertically aligning Datagrid header text

Tags: apache-flex, text, datagrid, header, vertical-alignment

I'm having some issues aligning the header text of a datagrid.
I'm using an embed font for the header text, and when applying the css, the header text behaves as if I'd set the text vertical align to top.
I'm trying to vertically center the text, but haven't found a way to make it work.

An image to give you a better idea:
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d9657df077.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d9657df077.jpg)

Any tip?

Regards,
BS_C3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a `headerRenderer`? A simple headerRenderer might look like:

```
<mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
  <mx:Label text="{data.name}"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

This will center the label vertically inside the box. You can position horizontally as well.

Comment: Hi.

Thanks for your answer. I thought about using a headerRenderer, but is there no other way to do it? Cause by default, the headers are correctly aligned... >_<

Answer (score 0):

Almost a year old but nevertheless..
Add a style like

// can be top/middle/bottom

```
.headerStyleClass {
        vertical-align:bottom;     
}
```

and then make use of this style in your column as follows

```
 <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="xyz"   headerText="Deriv/FX" ***headerStyleName="headerStyleClass">***
```

You should get the desired output